# Second Fundamental Form is multiple of First Fundamental Form implies that S is a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to verify a proof, trying to prove that if $II = aI$ on a surface $S\subset\mathbb{R^3}$ then $S$ is (part of) a sphere.

We are assuming that $a\neq 0$ since that would imply $S$ is a plane. My proof goes as follows:

We have the first fundamental form $I(x,y)$ given by:
$$
I(x,y) = \langle x,y \rangle
$$
And we have the second fundamental form $II(x,y)$ given by:
$$
II(x,y) = \langle -dN(x),y \rangle
$$
But from the hypthosesis we have that
$$
II = a\langle x,y \rangle = \langle ax,y \rangle
$$
And since this is valid for any vector $y$ then it must be that
$$
-dN(x) = ax
$$
So $x$ is an eigenvector of $-dN$ and $a$ is an eigenvalue. Since this was true for an arbitrary $x$ in the tangent plane to $S$ then we choose another $x'$ tangent to the surface and find that the same thing happens. Ie:
$$
-dN(x) = ax'
$$
So the two eigenvalues is just $a$ repeated. Which we can use to find that
$$
H = \frac{2a}{2} = a, K = a^2
$$
Gives a constant Mean and Gaussian curvature on $S$ and thus must be a sphere.

Comment: It is worth noting that the gaussian curvature is positive and not negative. If it were negative we would have a hyperboloid.

Comment: Hyperboloids do not have constant curvature. Indeed, by Hilbert's Theorem, there can be no complete surface of constant negative curvature in $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 3):

This is overkill (using some hard theorems at the very end, which, I believe, assume the surface is compact). In fact, it is a local result: If you know that $a$ is constant (which you are assuming), then you can show directly that the surface must be (a subset of) a sphere. If $\mathbf x$ is a local parametrization and $\mathbf N$ is the unit normal vector, consider $\mathbf y = \mathbf x + \frac1a\mathbf N$. Since $d\mathbf y = d\mathbf x + \dfrac1a d\mathbf N = d\mathbf x + \dfrac1a(-a\, d\mathbf x) = 0$, $\mathbf y = \mathbf y_0$ is a constant vector. This will be the center of your sphere, as $
\|\mathbf x-\mathbf y_0\| = 1/a$ is constant.